# Apache configuration - ProxyPassMatch with Regular Expressions - Getting error

Tags: apache, server, config, httpd.conf, proxypass

I am trying to set up Apache server and using the ProxyPassMatch with Regular expressions.  But I am getting an error "URL must be absolute"

Config:

```
ProxyPassMatch ^/assets/(.*)$ /virtual/assets/$1
```

Error:

> ProxyPass URL must be absolute!

Do I need to add anything in httpd.conf?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After fiddling around the internet I found that I will need to add an http in front of URLs.  It's mandatory and hence the error that URL must be absolute.